# Get the Pixel color on mouse point in Metro app using c#

Tags: c#, xaml, colors, microsoft-metro, pixel

I want to get the pixel color on mouse move in window 8 metro app using c#. I have found the code for this but all are using win32.dll .

But I don't want to use win32.dll.

Please help me to find the solution in window 8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me win32 would still work fine in Windows 8. And if something works fine why replace it? So there no specific graphic library for Windows 8. To get the new Windows 8 looks however its best to use Windows Presentation Foundation, which will work whenever you install .net 4.0, and can therefore even work on Windows 95.

Im assuming you want a solution with the new looks, then you should try this solution in WPF:

[WPF: Color under the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492128/wpf-color-under-the-pointer)

or

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36848/WPF-Image-Pixel-Color-Picker-Element
(yes it is possible to have the old window looks in WPF).

Comment: there is no win32 on windows 8 RT (ARM version)

Comment: Thanks For Response. But RenderTargetBitmap method does not exist in window 8 metro app. I want draw inking in canvas over a drowntext of Textblock. So that i want to get the pixel colour of canvas and through this want to identify the textblock drowntext.

Comment: use System.Windows.Media.Imaging. If you cannot, try adding it to your references: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx

or are you saying the environment you are working in does not support wpf?

Comment: metro app does not support  System.Windows.Media.Imagin namespace.Please Give a any help or code which will run  in metro app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think metro app support to get color pixel? I just find this on window form, WPF  or Android but never see in Metro app. Probably windows 8 have not APIs to do that (or have not yet).

> [Get color pixel in metro app (windows 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393846/get-color-pixel-in-metro-app-windows-8)