# Get color pixel in metro app (windows 8)

Tags: windows, xaml, colors, windows-runtime, pixel

I want to get color pixel on touch point and return a string (ex: #FFADD8E6).
I wonder if windows APIs support for that in metro app (windows 8). Anyone can answer for me or help me to find out the solution? Thank.

Comment: Do you want to do this in your own app? In that case, what language (C#/XAML or Javascript/HTML)? Otherwise, the answer is probably "no" (excepting some extremely deep hacking).

Comment: Thank @ma_il. I do it with C#/XAML. I also think the answer is "no" because I have not found any app (on store or sample on msdn) can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it isn't easy to do this. Assuming this is a XAML app (although the same logic applies to a WWA or DirectX app), you have a stack of rendering going on. The XAML objects are turned into textures inside the runtime, which get composited together by the hardware, along with potentially being combined with other applications, including components from the protected media pipeline, into the image that appears on screen. This image, which is what the user sees, only exists in the frame buffer of the GPU, so there really isn't anywhere for the CPU, and therefore your app, to read it from. While it would be possible to read it, it would almost certainly involve stalling the whole system wide rendering pipeline, then copying the whole frame buffer into system memory. That would be *very* slow.